# English name of all lines through 3 given skew lines? (At one time called "Regelschar" in German)

Tags: geometry, terminology, projective-geometry

> How is the set of all lines through 3 skew lines called in English?

In projective geometry, or for that matter Euclidean space, this is an important set.

And how is it called in German nowadays? It used to be called "Regelschar" in German, but the German Wikipedia has nothing about it.

I would like to find an article that has collected some esp. Euclidean properties of such a configuration.

Comment: Over ${\Bbb R}$ it's a hyperboloid of one sheet.

Comment: In English it seems to be regulus. https://www.dict.cc/german-english/Regelschar.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulus_(geometry)

Comment: See [Hilbert Cohn-Vossen: Geometry and the Imagination](https://archive.org/details/geometryimaginat00davi_0) pp. 14-15.

Comment: Regulus and hyperboloid are ok. Should I now delete the question?

Comment: @Jan-Magnus Økland : Are there some examples/ images / parameterizations in it ? ( other than the 1- sheet hyperboloid? Could Translation be " neat bundle"  ( perhaps from regelmaessiger Schar ?)